# How to nullify the column based on flag in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have list of columns and corresponding flag. Based on flag all the values of the columns should get replaced by NULL. How to achieve the same?

Example:

**Table 1**

```
List_of_columns | Flag
Column1 | 1
Column2 | 0
Column3 | 0
```

**Table 2**

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
```

Based on Table 1 Flag (if 1), I want to set values to NULL in Table 2.

Comment: Disha, we need also to know how Table1 and Table2 are connected. What is their join?

Comment: Thanks for the question. No Tables are not connected.

Comment: Are you just trying to null out the column in table 2 based on the List_of_columns value where the flag column is 1?

Comment: @Jesse Correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current understanding of the question is: you are trying to check Table 1 for Flag = 1, then take the value of List_of_columns from that record and null out the records for that column in Table 2.

Here is an example on how to address this particular issue. This example uses a cursor and dynamic sql.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    column_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    flag INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    column1 VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    column2 VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    column3 VARCHAR(100) NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.table1 
VALUES ('column1', 1), 
    ('column2', 0), 
    ('column3', 1);

INSERT INTO dbo.table2 VALUES ('test1', 'test2', 'test3'), ('test9', 'test10', 'test11');

SELECT column_name
INTO #columnstonull
FROM dbo.table1
WHERE flag = 1;


DECLARE @columnname VARCHAR(100), @sqlstatement NVARCHAR(max)

DECLARE columnnullcursor SCROLL CURSOR FOR
    SELECT column_name
    FROM #columnstonull

OPEN columnnullcursor

FETCH FIRST 
    FROM 
        columnnullcursor
    INTO 
        @columnname

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
    BEGIN

        SET @sqlstatement = 'UPDATE t SET t.' + @columnname + ' = NULL FROM dbo.table2 t'
        EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @sqlstatement


        FETCH NEXT 
            FROM 
                columnnullcursor
            INTO 
                @columnname
    END

CLOSE columnnullcursor
DEALLOCATE columnnullcursor


SELECT *
FROM dbo.table2

DROP TABLE #columnstonull
DROP TABLE table1
DROP TABLE table2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

```
Update tbl
set Column1 = null
where Column1 = 'Flag 1'
```

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nullif()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) :

```
select nullif(col, 'Flag 1')
```

This will replace `null` where column has `flag 1` found. If you want null only then add `where` clause :

```
select null as col
from table t
where t.col = 'Flag 1';
```

**EDIT :**  You can do `cross join` :

```
UPDATE T2    
      SET T2.COL1 = (CASE WHEN COLS = 'COL1' THEN NULL ELSE T2.COL1 END),
          T2.COL2 = (CASE WHEN COLS = 'COL2' THEN NULL ELSE T2.COL2 END),
          T2.COL3 = (CASE WHEN COLS = 'COL3' THEN NULL ELSE T2.COL3 END)
FROM table2 AS T2 CROSS JOIN
     table1 AS T1
WHERE FLAG = 1;
```

Comment: @dishakedar. . . Edit the question add some sample data along with desired result will helpful.

Comment: I have added an example. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can either nullify those columns this way :

```
update Table2 set Column1 = null
where (select Flag from Table1 where List_of_columns = 'Column1') = 1

update Table2 set Column2 = null
where (select Flag from Table1 where List_of_columns = 'Column2') = 1

update Table2 set Column3 = null
where (select Flag from Table1 where List_of_columns = 'Column3') = 1
```

Or use dynamic SQL if you want it to work for any unknown number of columns (build your SQL by code and execute it using [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).